# npm-config Environment Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, config

I saw that best way to store some secret strings is using config package and environment variables. This is how I set it up.

1. Created a config folder with 2 files (`default.json`, `custom-environment-variables.json`)
2. In `default.json` I created this:

   ```json
   {
     "passPrivateKey": ""
   }
   ```
3. In `custom-environment-variables.json` I created this:

   ```json
   {
     "passPrivateKey": "nodeProject_passPrivateKey"
   }
   ```
4. After I set the variable in terminal with this command:

   ```
   npm config set nodeProject_passPrivateKey=randomKey
   ```

When I am reading the variable from terminal with command below it works fine and shows the correct value

```
npm config get nodeProject_passPrivateKey
```

However in code I have these lines:

```
if (!config.get("nodeProject_passPrivateKey")) {
  console.error("nodeProject_passPrivateKey has not been set");
}
```

So yeah the problem is this method `config.get()` is not reading the value and I am getting the error not set from above. I tried doing everything in vs code as admin, and using `config.get` on `"nodeProject_passPrivateKey"` and `"passPrivateKey"` but the method is still not reading any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

You create an **.env** file where you store all your secrets and you access them through

```
    process.env.myvar
```

Comment: Looks like this package is way more popular and really simple to use. I tried it and seems that everything is working fine so thanks for help.